# How to insert DataTable in DataGridView from a by class and display in form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to create class like this 
[class insert DataTable in DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1SY4.jpg)

```
 class Test_Class 
 {
    public void test()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        dt1.Clear();
        dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt1.Columns.Add("BDate");

        dt1.Rows.Add("Joh", 1997);
        dt1.Rows.Add("Keylor", 1995);
        form1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
    }
}
```

and code in Form1 like this
[Form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM31J.jpg)

```
          Test_Class test_Class = new Test_Class();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test_Class.test();
    }
```

[Form1 designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iaib3.jpg) 
But this code doesn't work
I use this simple example to facilitate understanding of the problem
went click in button1 There is nothing

Comment: Please paste your code in your question instead of using screenshots. Also try to provide some more information on what exactly the problem is that you are trying to fix.

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not a helpful problem description! - What happens? Nothing? Errors? (Which?) Crashes? Wrong results? (Which?)

Comment: Yes.. doesn't work if he is give me Errors it is good i can solve but There is nothing

Comment: My question is why this code is not work?

Comment: My problem with this line
 form1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;

Comment: When delete the Form1 form1 = new Form1(); i can't call dataGridView in the class
or another Form

Comment: How many forms do you want to show?

Comment: In this example just one, But in my program i have 5 forms

Comment: _In this example just one_ I thought so. The mistake is that you create two :-) See the answer!

Comment: Actually in my program, i have dataGridView ( in Form1 ) contact with DataBase (SQL server)  when click button Edit open another Form (Form2), went click button save to saveed changes (button save in Form2)  evre think it good just  when Form2  closed and return to Form1  dataGridView  database is not refreshed

Comment: How can i make dataGridView Auto Update when close Form2.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: You will need to write code for that. If you have saved the changes to the datasource you simply set the source agein. Again you need to have references, maybe you need to make controls or vrialbes public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to with DataTable, DataGridView or DataSource. It has only to do with accessing the correct form. You create an extra instance instead of referncing the correct one.

The classic way is to pass the reference from Form1 to any other forms you create or, in this case, another class..

Change the class constructor to receive a reference to the 'real' Form1:

```
class Test_Class 
{
  Form1 form1 = null;                     // <==
  public void test(Form1 form1_)         // <==
  {
    form1 = form1_;                     // <==
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Clear();
    dt1.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt1.Columns.Add("BDate");

    dt1.Rows.Add("Joh", 1997);
    dt1.Rows.Add("Keylor", 1995);
    form1.dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
  }
}
```

And create it passing out a reference to it:

```
 Test_Class test_Class = new Test_Class(this);        // <==
```

Now the test class can work with a vaild reference to the real and visible form.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)